# How to protect the /api route when using Swagger

Tags: swagger, nestjs

I a NestJS server with the Swagger module.

If I GET the `/api` it returns the api documentation, that's OK.

But, when I make requests using the Swagger documentation it changes my database. The users created in the Swagger interface are created in my actual database.

Is there a way to prevent that. Or at least put some authentication in the `/api` route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Swagger docs let you do ACTUAL REQUESTS.

It is exactly the same request as you would perform with e.g. curl, Postman or any other http client.

Swagger docs is not like SANDBOX.

^^^ This is examplation why:

> The users created in the Swagger interface are created in my actual database.